# ranking multiple data frames and summing across them in R

Tags: r, sum, ranking, data-manipulation

I have 10 data frames with 2 columns each, I'm calling the dataframes a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i and j.

The first column in each data frame is called s for sequences and the second is p for p-values corresponding to each sequence. The s column contains the same sequences across all 10 data frames, essentially the only difference is in the p-values.
Below is a short version of data frame a, which has 600,000 rows.

```
s       p
gtcg    0.06
gtcgg   0.05
gggaa   0.07
cttg    0.05
```

I want to rank each dataframe by p-value, the smallest p-value should get a rank of 1 and equal p-values should get the same rank. Each final data frame should be in this format:

```
    s       p_rank_a
    gtcg    2
    gtcgg   1
    gggaa   3
    cttg    1
```

I've used this to do one:

> r<-rank(a$p)
>
> cbind(a$s,r)

but I'm not very familiar with loops and I don't know how to do this automatically. Ultimately I would like a final file that has the s column and in the next column the rank sum of all the ranks across all data frames for each specific sequence.
SO basically this:

```
s       ranksum_P_a-j
gtcg    34
gtcgg   5
gggaa   5009093
cttg    499
```

Please help and thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the rank of `gggaa` be 4 instead of 3?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put all the `data.frames` in a `list` and then use `lapply` and `transform` as follows:

```
my_l <- list(a,b,c) # all your data.frames
# you can use rank but it'll give you the average in case of ties
# lapply(my_l, function(x) transform(x, rank_p = rank(p)))

# I prefer this method instead
my_o <- lapply(my_l, function(x) transform(x, p = as.numeric(factor(p))))

# now bind them in to a single data.frame
my_o <- do.call(rbind, my_o)

# now paste them
aggregate(data = my_o, p ~ s, function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))

#       s     p
# 1  cttg 1,1,1
# 2 gggaa 3,3,3
# 3  gtcg 2,2,2
# 4 gtcgg 1,1,1
```

**Edit** since you've asked for a potential faster solution (due to large data), I'd suggest, like @Ricardo, a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
# bind all your data.frames together
dt <- rbindlist(my_l) # my_l is your list of data.frames

# replace p-value with their "rank"
dt[, p := as.numeric(factor(p))]

# set key
setkey(dt, "s")

# combine them using `,`
dt[, list(p_ranks = paste(p, collapse=",")), by=s]
```

Try this out:

Comment: thank you again. I will use this with the other one you answered and combine them. these data frames are from 600,000 to 2.4 million rows long, do you know of a faster program I could use. I know python a little but that is about it

Answer (score 2):

for a single data.frame, you can do it one line, as follows:
*credit to @Arun for pointing out to use `as.numeric(factor(p))`*

```
library(data.table)
aDT <- data.table(a)[, p_rank := as.numeric(factor(p))]
```

I would suggest keeping all the data.frames in a single list, so that you can easily iterate over them. 
Since your date.frames are letters, it's easy to collect the ten of them:

```
# collect them all
allOfThem <- lapply(letters[1:10], get, envir=.GlobalEnv)   
# keep in mind you named an object `c`

# convert to DT and create the ranks
allOfThem <- lapply(allOfThem, function(x) data.table(x)[, p_rank := as.numeric(factor(p))])
```

---

on a separate note:  it might be good habbit to start avoiding naming objects "`c`" and other common functions in `R`. otherwise, you will find that you'll start encountering many "unexplainable" behaviors which, after you've beaten your 
head against a wall for an hour trying to debug it, you realize that you've overwritten the name of a function.  *This has never happened to me :)*

Comment: I'm not sure if `order(rank(p))` is what is desired here. for ex: if `p=c(0.06, 0.05, 0.07, 0.05)`, then `rank(p) = c(3, 1.5, 4, 1.5)` and `order(.) = 2,4,1,3` while the desired result is `2,1,3,1`. And `order(p)` is the same as `order(rank(p))`

Comment: @Arun, you are absolutely correct.  In my head I was thinking `floor(rank(p))`, but even that would not be totally correct.  I've edited my answer.